# Return few lines back if condition is true

Tags: ruby

Let's say that I have this simple `if-elsif-else` block of code.

```
def
  # some code...
  input = get.chomp
  if input == 1
    puts "foo"
  elsif input == 2
    puts "bar"
  else
    # exit
  end
  # some more code...
end
```

How do I tell program to go back and ask for input again for cases `1` and `2` and continue with code within this method if `else` is triggered? I do not want to go back to start of the method, instead I just want to back to `input` variable declaration.

Comment: One way of doing it: Outside of the method, you can have a loop, and within that loop, you can call this method. If this method returns from the `input == 1` or the `input == 2`, you tell the loop to rerun the method again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def
  # some code...
  loop do
    input = get.chomp
    if input == 1
      puts "foo"
      break
    elsif input == 2
      puts "bar"
      break
    end
  end
  # some more code...
end
```

Note: Your two `if`/`elsif` conditions will never be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
# main procedure
# defined here so other functions could be declared after
# the main procedure is called at the bottom
def main

  loop do
    puts "Insert a number"
    input = gets.chomp.to_i

    if isValidInput input
      puts case input
        when 1 
          "foo"
        when 2 
          "bar"
      end
      break
    end
  end #loop

  puts "Other code would execute here"

end

# Validity Checker
# makes sure your input meets your condition
def isValidInput(input)
  if [1,2].include? input
    return true
  end
  return false
end


main
```

Comment: You only need the line `[1,2].include? input` in `isValidInput`.

Comment: Correct. You don't need the function either, this is all setup for something more involved